# Angularjs directive append $http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create an angularjs directive that appends new directive after ajax call.

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

// This directive is simple search operation.

app.directive("search", function("$http", function($http){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="searchText"/> <button ng-click="search()">Search</button>',
        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.search = function(){
                $http({url: "..."})
                    .then(function(response){
                        $scope.searchResult = response.data;
                    });
            }
        },
        link: function(scope,element){
            var directiveHtml = ('<search-result></search-result>');
            var directiveElement = $compile(directiveHtml)(scope);
            element.append(directiveElement);
        }       
    }   
});

app.directive("searchResult", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "list of the search result",
        link: function(scope,element){

        }
    }
});
```

I want to append the directive after $http result. But it appends before. 
I applied $scope.$watch(scope.searchResult) but does not work.

Comment: $watch should also have a handler. i.e. a function to execute when the value changes - `$scope.$watch([expression returning watched value],              [change handler],  [objectEquality?]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    controller: function($scope){
        $scope.search = function(){
            $http({url: "..."})
                .then(function(response){
                    $scope.searchResult = response.data;
                });
        }
    },
    link: function(scope,element){
        $scope.$watch('searchResult', function(results) {
          if (results) {
               var directiveHtml = ('<search-result></search-result>');
               var directiveElement = $compile(directiveHtml)(scope);
               element.append(directiveElement);
          }
        })
    }
```

Or you can use `ng-if` in `html`

Answer (score 0):

```
controller: function($scope, $http){
            $scope.search = function(){
                $http({url: "..."})
                    .then(function(response){
                        $scope.searchResult = response.data;
                        var directiveHtml = ('<search-result></search-result>');
                        var directiveElement = $compile(directiveHtml)($scope);
                        angular.element(document.getElementById('id')).append(directiveElement);
                    });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Link function will be called while rendering directive and at the same time element will be appended, instead of appending it in link append it in ajax response in controller. Give id to searh directive e.g. <search-e id="id"></search-e> ,